# Vue2 leaflet forcing map to have 100% height of parent container

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet

How to make Vue2-leaflet map have 100% height of its parent container?

When I set its style to `style="height: 100%"` it is overwriting whole page on first interaction with the map and tile layer isn't showed at all.

Comment: can you create an example on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: @Anatoly https://jsfiddle.net/be07jrwa/ I would like the map to take all space of #map-wrapper div but it adds scroll.

Comment: @stasiekz In your Fiddle it adds a scrollbar even if you remove the `l-map` completely. You've set `height: 100%` on `map-wrapper`, so once that's added to the `100px` of `some-div` it overflows. For that example I'd just use flex-box instead but I'm not convinced that it's demonstrating the same problem you originally described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc(100% - 100px)` for `#map-wrapper` because `#some-div` has a height of 100px in your example.
Then the scrollbar disappears.

```
#some-div {
  height: 100px;
}

#map-wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  margin: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yLe9n1uk/

Or use a flexbox for the parent div (`#app`):

```
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#some-div {
  height: 100px;
}

#map-wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xo5z8r7q/